# includeFlat Gradle directive interpretation misbehave

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm here to describe a subtle issue about Grails and his import feature supplied by Gradle.

My specs:

OS Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

My Grails version is 3.2.0.M2

Java version is jdk1.8.0_31

And I'm using Intellij 2016

1. I have created a project (Foo) with a module (Bar)
2. Bar module exists under Foo main project and has his CallMeController
3. Running Foo app and calling the url {urlbase}/CallMe will result in a correct controller call
4. Now I move the Bar folder outside the Foo folder project
5. I change the settings.gradle file using an includeFlat in place of include directive which should be supported without any problem as reported in the official documentation
6. Intellij recognize the project structure correctly
7. Running the application and calling the url {urlbase}/CallMe will result into a 404 Not found

In the files linked below (Working example and Not working example) there are the two simple projects which reproduce the issue.
The working one is related with include directive, the second (not working) one is related with includeFlat directive.

Is this a normal behavior?

[Working example](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/files/476972/Foo-working.zip)

[Not working example](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/files/476973/Foo-not-working.zip)